# Does the votes of a question change if the question is edited?

Tags: support, edits, voting, bump, locked-votes

Does the votes of a question change if the question is edited? I have the same question about the answers.

Comment: Close voters: the question is clear enough, OP asking if the votes are changing automatically (e.g. downvotes removed) upon edit. Accepting the answer kind of proves this as well.

Comment: Why do you think editing would affect votes that have been cast?  That would make disposing of downvotes trivially easy.

Comment: Yeah. I was just confused, because the answer was changed. I understand now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Editing a post does not change the votes that are on it.

However, editing a post will bump it back to the active questions list. This will indirectly attract fresh attention from users who may end up casting votes.

Also, votes are locked after 5 minutes of placing your up or down vote. Which means you are no longer able to change or remove your vote. When a post is edited, this lock is removed and you may change or remove your vote again.